# simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui (core dumped)

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I run the command:

```
  optirun roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch
```

and [gazebo_gui-3] process has died

The error messages are as follow:
http://notepad.cc/sidafra78

I use ubuntu11.10 and ros fuerte
How to solve it?
thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2456/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui-(core-dumped)/) by [lian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/319/lian/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I don't know what the optirun command does to set the DISPLAY env variable.. but on my machine, when I don't set the DISPLAY variable to something useful I get the message

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  146 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  5 (X_GLXMakeCurrent)
  Serial number of failed request:  22
  Current serial number in output stream:  22
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

for reference, your error messages was slightly different from mine..

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  72 (X_PutImage)
  Serial number of failed request:  38
  Current serial number in output stream:  40
Error [Transport.cc:102] Unable to get topic namespaces in [50] tries.
Error [Node.cc:68] No namespace found
```

To fix my problem, I run xvfb (can be run in the background or in another terminal)

> Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24

and then run gazebo

> DISPLAY=:1 rosrun gazebo gazebo
> my.world

If there was a display already open on the machine that I had access to (e.g. if I was physically logged in through a GUI or something), I could have also set the variable to that value as well.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) with karma: 319 on 2013-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/319/lian/) on 2013-05-10**:
I try your method,but running gazebo still is failed.Is any other solution ?  thank you.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2013-05-12**:
Hello, what type of graphics card are you using and what driver are you using for the card?

**Comment by [lian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/319/lian/) on 2013-05-21**:
Due to  optimus tech doesn't have linux driver, so I use bumblebee(each execution has to add key word:optirun).

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2013-05-23**:
Maybe you could post a question here http://whoochee.blogspot.com/2012/12/optimus-and-discrete-nvidia-gpu-under.html (they claim that "everything works")